# ssh tunnel doesn't work

Tags: ssh, port, forwarding, tunnel

Even though tunnelling using ssh is a well discussed topic in internet, I couldn't make my setup proper. This is what the problem statement I have

-> I have two servers A and B.
-> I am trying to create a tunnel from A to B

-> In B I have echo server which is listening on port 34567

-> In A I have executed the command `ssh -L 4444:10.106.251.90:34567 127.0.0.1`

-> Netstat shows as follows

~ # netstat -na | grep 4444
tcp 0 0 127.0.0.1:4444 0.0.0.0:* LISTEN 
tcp 0 0 ::1:4444 :::* LISTEN 
-> In B I tried to check `netstat -na | grep 4444` but there was no reference of it

-> In A I have echo client which writes into 127.0.0.1:4444

-> If I execute client in A, it doesn't forward. Instead it gives some 0 length string always

Is there any thing that I am missing here ?

Thanks
~S

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
ssh -L 4444:127.0.0.1:34567 user@10.106.251.90
```

This will open port *4444* on your local machine, forwarding packets to port `34567` of the remote machine.

```
# using on local
telnet 127.0.0.1 4444

# is the same as

# on remote
telnet 127.0.0.1 34567
```

Comment: Didn't work .. is there any ssh configuration parameters that I need to look into in client/server side ?